# ¿Por qué el verbo "tener" introduce una "i" en ciertas conjugaciones, como "tú tienes" o "ellos tienen"?

Tags: verbos, etimología, tiempos-verbales, conjugación

Estaba pensando en el verbo tener y su conjugación en el presente del indicativo:

| persona | singular | plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.ª | tengo | tenemos |
| 2.ª | ti`e`nes | tenéis |
| 3.ª | ti`e`ne | ti`e`nen |

Vemos que la 3ª persona del plural, así como la 2ª y 3ª del singular introducen una *i* entre la "t" y la "e".

Claramente es un verbo irregular que la RAE describe en [Modelos de conjugación verbal](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal) bajo la introducción:

> **Verbos irregulares**
>
> Se incluyen bajo este epígrafe tanto los verbos de irregularidad
> propia, cuyo paradigma es único (ir, ser, etc.), como los que sirven
> de modelo a otros verbos irregulares (acertar, agradecer, etc.).
> También se incluye aquí el verbo leer —modelo de otros verbos como
> creer o proveer—, que aun siendo regular desde el punto de vista
> morfológico, no lo es desde el punto de vista gráfico-articulatorio,
> ya que el sonido vocálico /i/ de algunas desinencias, cuando queda
> entre vocales, se transforma en el sonido consonántico /y/; así, la
> raíz le- + la desinencia -ió no da leió, sino leyó; le- + -iera no da
> leiera, sino leyera, etc.

Mi educación nunca incluyó el latín y mis conocimientos de etimologías son bastante triviales (en ambos sentidos: tanto por cosas de perogrullo como por preguntas del trivial), por lo que lo mismo es obvio para muchos, pero... ¿qué sentido histórico-etimológico tiene la introducción de la "i" en la conjugación?

Comment: ¿Porqué del latín teneo quedó tengo, con una "ene" intercalada?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Muy resumido, /e/ breve latina en posición tónica diptonga en español a /ie/. Ocurre de forma regular: *feram* > "fiera", *herbam* > "hierba", etc. Es una cuestión fonética.

Comment: Fantástico, muchas gracias. ¿Tienes algún recurso en el que se detallen estas combinaciones? Seguro que será una fuente de descubrimientos interesantes.

Comment: Puedes mirarlo en cualquier manual de gramática histórica, como el de Ralph Penny. También hay en internet algunos manuales gratuitos en pdf.

Comment: Estuve leyendo ayer un trozo del "Gramática histórica del español" de Ralph Penny y uf, qué gozada.