# ¿Cómo elige la RAE las palabras que son "válidas"?

Tags: etimología, historia, rae, extranjerismos, dle

Últimamente le he estado dando vueltas a cuán talibán debe ser uno a la hora de usar palabras no aceptadas por la RAE. Todo empezó cuando Diego puso el foco preguntando [Cuál es la mejor traducción para “Spoiler”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17188/1674). En ella me mencionaba (gracias desde aquí) como persona que ha ido preguntando en este sitio cómo decir tal o cual anglicismo usando una palabra autóctona; esto es, cómo evitar extranjerismos cuando el castellano ya dispone de palabras para definir un concepto.

En paralelo, llevo unos días leyendo el apartado de Léxico del *Manual de gramática histórica* de Ralph Penny que me [recomendó Paco](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17104/por-qu%C3%A9-el-verbo-tener-introduce-una-i-en-ciertas-conjugaciones-como-t%C3%BA-t/17105#comment22877_17105). Ahí he visto la gran cantidad de palabras del castellano que vienen de otros idiomas. No ya solo del latín, sino del portugués, catalán, alemán, francés, griego, vasco, árabe y otros. Son palabras, en fin, tan arraigadas ahora mismo en la lengua que a nadie se le ocurriría buscar una palabra española para no utilizar el italianismo [*bufón*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6FLfOZc%7C6FMXtw5), el catalanismo [*avería*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4YZmqpT%7C4Yba16F) o el lusismo [*carambola*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7PtHWgl).

Como colofón a estas lecturas, leía el otro día la columna de Javier Marías [*Narcisismo hasta la enfermedad*](http://elpaissemanal.elpais.com/columna/narcisismo-enfermedad/) en la que sacaba a colación el caso del uso de las palabras *cáncer* y *autista* para registrar comportamientos, además de definir enfermedades:

> (...) Este sentido metafórico de la palabra está extendidísimo, y a la RAE
>   no le cabe sino registrarlo. Esta institución, en contra de lo que
>   muchos quisieran, no prohíbe ni impone nada; tampoco juzga; a lo sumo
>   advierte, mediante las marcas “Vulgar” o “Negativo”, que tal o cual
>   vocablo pueden resultar malsonantes o denigratorios.

Todo este cúmulo de lecturas me hicieron pensar que probablemente las palabras tienen cierto rango de aceptación: desde algo absolutamente incorrecto a algo aceptado por la RAE, pasando por "bueno, decidlo, pero no demasiado", "me lo estoy pensando", "[tengo una palabra autóctona pero me quedo con el extranjerismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17248/1674)" y "vale, lo acepto en nada". Todo esto puesto en la coctelera de las tendencias, las variedades por países, las filias y fobias de los académicos, etc.

Así pues, y para no hacer una pregunta tan amplia que sea difícil encajar en un sitio como este, ¿cuál es el proceso por el que la RAE acaba aceptando una palabra? ¿Existe una gradación en cuanto a lo válida que es una palabra? ¿Cuáles deberían ser los límites a la hora de utilizar una palabra en un texto escrito: solamente lo que acepta la RAE para textos formales?

Comment: Creo que el proceso es más bien al contrario: el lenguaje evoluciona primero en el habla, luego los textos escritos evolucionan reflejando el habla, y luego la RAE evoluciona reflejando lo que se escribe. Si siempre se escribiera como dice la RAE, ésta no evolucionaría y habría un desfase importante entre la RAE y el habla. Me interesan mucho más las otras preguntas, acerca del proceso de aceptación y si existe un indicador que mida la bondad de una palabra (desde el punto de vista de ser aceptada).

Comment: Acá hay una respuesta sobre cómo la RAE mete palabras en el diccionario: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5220/c%C3%B3mo-se-legalizan-los-superlativos-irregulares/5227#5227

Comment: @CarlosAlejo nótese que menciono los textos escritos, aunque debí añadir _formales_. En ellos creo que lo correcto es usar términos aceptados; ya en  textos más informales, o en el habla, es donde se generan nuevos términos que acaban "subiendo" hasta tocar todos los ámbitos.

Comment: En la web de la RAE tienen [un formulario](http://www.rae.es/formulario/unidrae) para proponer nuevos significados a palabras existentes o incluso para proponer nuevos términos. Lo curioso es que afirman que "el diccionario académico no recoge voces inexistentes en la lengua escrita".

Comment: Posiblemente, @fedorqui. Una cosa que me llama mucho la atención es que los ejemplos que suelen mencionar el DRAE y el DPD son (casi) siempre artículos periodísticos, o diálogos de novelas, textos que en general reflejan el habla cotidiana. De ahí a la RAE y de ahí a textos formales.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo eso [me dice la RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/750324269461213184) en Twitter: _Se parte siempre de la documentación textual y lexicográfica._

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Esto es coherente con el criterio de la RAE de no aceptar palabras de moda o de ámbito restringido. De hacerlo, el diccionario estaría lleno de palabras que se han usado durante unos pocos años y luego olvidado, o que solo se usan en lugares muy concretos. Si una palabra supera esa fase de moda y se asienta en el lenguaje (aunque sea coloquial), o su uso se extiende, acabará apareciendo en textos y habrá una base para incluirla en el diccionario.

Comment: Esta pregunta estaria mejor en META, y no aqui. No entiendo los moderadores....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La tarea de la RAE es registrar el lenguaje tal y como es hablado por sus hablantes.

Si una gran mayoría de sus hablantes usan una determinada palabra, la RAE la registra. Generalmente como un vulgarismo/coloquianismo, cuando la palabra se normaliza en la sociedad, pasa a ser una palabra más.

Si estas palabras son extranjeras, suelen ser normalizadas para que se adapten a la grafía y pronunciación españolas. Por ejemplo la palabra *airbag*, pronunciada en inglés: *[érbag]* , pasa a pronunciarse *airbág*.

Ahora bien, cuando existe una palabra española equivalente al extranjerismo, la RAE se resiste a añadirla. Por ejemplo con la palabra *selfie*, argumentando que ya existe un equivalente en español (*autofoto*). No obstante, solo es cuestión de tiempo que la acaben añadiendo.

Hay una [entrevista con un académico de la RAE](http://www.lavanguardia.com/cultura/20141016/54417975191/nuevo-diccionario-rae-blaugrana-birra.html) donde se trata este tema:

> **¿Es pronto para introducir ‘selfie’?**
>
> Esa es aún más pronto. En un coloquio un señor muy enfadado con la
>   palabra ‘selfie’ me decía que teníamos que adoptar la palabra
>   ‘autofoto’. Pues muy bien, a ver quién es el que consigue que autofoto
>   sea la que triunfe. Ni la Academia ni nadie puede gobernar los usos
>   léxicos de 400 y pico millones de personas. Y ‘selfie’ no ha habido
>   tiempo ni de considerarla.
>
> **¿Le preocupa el alud de palabras del inglés?**
>
> Personalmente a mí no. Es posible que yo sea uno de los académicos que
>   menos le preocupan los anglicismos. No soy muy alarmista ni muy
>   catastrofista en esto de los extranjerismos. A los historiadores de la
>   lengua como yo, eso nos da una visión un poco más relativizadora y
>   desdramatizadora. En el siglo XVIII español había verdadera alarma
>   ante la profusión de galicismos y se llegó a profetizar que el francés
>   iba a acabar con la lengua española. Las lenguas son sabias y saben
>   aceptar lo que necesitan y no rebasar un cupo tolerable de
>   extranjerismos crudos.
>
> Hay compensaciones, como la palabra ‘tableta’, que está triunfando.
>   Pero empeñarse en no meter ‘selfie’ y meter ‘autofoto’ sería ingenuo.
>   No se puede pensar que la Academia tiene ese poder de convicción sobre
>   tantos millones de usuarios para proscribir el empleo de ‘selfie’. Si
>   al final hay que aceptarla, como decía Espronceda, “un cadáver más qué
>   importa al mundo”, pues un anglicismo más qué importa al mundo.

En cuanto su uso:

- Informal: Es correcto usar extranjerismos, siempre que estén aceptados y no se abuse.
- Formal: Evitarlos, usar solo los que estén muy aceptados. Palabras como selfie pueden ser válidas incluso aunque no estén aceptadas por la RAE aún, pero debe usarse entrecomillado y en cursiva.

Comment: Entrecomillado *o* en cursiva. Son opciones excluyentes. Según la RAE, los extranjerismos crudos deberían escribirse en cursiva, pero, si no se dispone de esa tipografía, se puede sustituir por el entrecomillado. Por lo demás, estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto, y sin que tenga mucho que ver con la pregunta o la respuesta: los de La Vanguardia se han lucido escribiendo *estrangerismo* en una entrevista sobre lengua española :D

Comment: Eso del "tal y como es hablado"|, no es cierto. También existe lenguaje escrito que a veces ni se "habla" en circunstancias "normales"......