# Uso de "mouse" en América Latina

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, hispanoamérica, rae, extranjerismos

Quisiera lanzar una pregunta para complementar la que acaba de hacer [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui) sobre el [proceso de adaptación de palabras por la RAE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17317/12637), y el uso que se debe hacer de las recomendaciones de ésta en textos formales.

Hace varios años hubo [una gran controversia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discusi%C3%B3n:Rat%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)/Temas_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADsticos) en la Wikipedia, al respecto del artículo sobre el [ratón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)) como periférico de un ordenador. Se ve que en América Latina es mayoritario el uso de *mouse* sobre el término *ratón*, por lo que se adujo que al ser mayoría el número de personas que usaban el primer término, el artículo de la Wikipedia debería ser renombrado. Y así fue, se renombró a "Mouse (informática)", y "Ratón (informática)" redirigía al primero. Durante un tiempo fue así, pero al final se siguió la recomendación de la RAE. Se argumentó que un artículo de la Wikipedia en español no debería tener un título en inglés existiendo un calco admitido y recomendado, y el artículo pasó a ser denominado "Ratón (informática)", mientras que ahora es "Mouse (informática)" el que redirige al anterior.

Este es un caso en el que la recomendación de la RAE prevalece. Además, si miramos en Ngram [el uso de ambos términos](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rat%C3%B3n%2Cmouse&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crat%C3%B3n%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmouse%3B%2Cc0), se ve que "ratón" va siempre en alza, mientras que "mouse" se estanca y hacia el final de la gráfica comienza a decrecer:

[image: ratón vs mouse]

Sé que "ratón" tiene otra acepción obvia, pero el aumento en su uso desde finales de los años 80 no deja lugar a dudas de que la nueva acepción se usa muchísimo.

Mi teoría al respecto de la pregunta de fedorqui es que la evolución es: primero evoluciona el habla, luego la escritura que refleja el habla, y por último la RAE. Las recomendaciones de la RAE pueden alterar los textos formales, pero ¿pueden también alterar el habla? ¿Existe algún tipo de transición en los lugares donde se dice "mouse" hacia la palabra "ratón" en la expresión oral?

Comment: Este me parece un caso muy bonito. Parece que aquí la RAE no se limitó a comentar desde la barrera y asumir como inevitable que se iba a acabar diciendo _mouse_, sino que hizo de muro de contención de la palabra original. A la vista de la gráfica que muestras se ve que su posicionamiento fue tenido en cuenta y acabó influyendo en cómo se denomina. Vaya, que el observador influyó en la muestra : )

Comment: Pues yo no sé que tanta atención le pongan a la RAE en España pero aquí oímos hablar mas de la NASA que de la RAE. jajaajja. El uso de ratón o mouse por estos lados es según mi observación muy equilibrado. Los que trabajamos en informática o afines tendemos a usar mouse mientras que el resto de las personas los usa indistintamente.

Comment: Esa comparación no dice nada, salvo que distinga mágicamente entre las distintas acepciones de _ratón_. Por otro lado, Wikipedia es prácticamente uno de los brazos ejecutores de las recomendaciones de la RAE (aunque no debería serlo), por lo que no me extrañaría que el nivel de adopción de tales recomendaciones sea proporcional a la popularidad de Wikipedia.

Comment: @angus el uso de "ratón" en textos se mantuvo estable hasta aproximadamente 1990, momento en el cual su uso se disparó, influenciado claramente por esta nueva acepción. Interesante lo que comentas de que la Wikipedia pueda influenciar más en el idioma que la propia RAE.

Comment: @DGaleano buenísimo lo de la NASA, toda la razón. El papel de RAE (aunque con excepciones) suele ser mayormente pasivo. En todo caso, es muy curioso que los términos se usen indistintamente en el habla común. Ese contexto es el que me interesa precisamente para la pregunta, saber si hay alguna tendencia clara sobre el uso mayoritario de un término sobre otro, o si mi pregunta tardará aún un tiempo en tener respuesta.

Comment: ¿Pero cuántos usuarios reales del idioma han leído "mouse" o "ratón" alguna vez en el DRAE o en la Wikipedia? No creo que vayamos a preferir una u otra palabra por recomendación o por decreto.

Comment: Tal vez las palabras no se lean en el DRAE, pero los escritores meticulosos de manuales de uso, páginas web, libros de informática y demás textos formales al respecto, sí buscarán si hay alguna recomendación de la RAE al respecto y la seguirán, haciendo cada lectura un poco más de mella en el habla del lector. A las palabras se las lleva el viento, pero lo escrito permanece. En los textos, _mouse_ partía en desventaja y este podría ser un caso del [efecto Mateo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_Mateo) (por [Mt 13:12](https://www.bibliatodo.com/biblia/Mateo-hebreo-duTillet/mateo-13-12)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que he encontrado una forma de separar el uso de *ratón* en informática del resto, pero no es magia: es ciencia (como toda la magia).

[image: Abrupta aparición de las expresiones "puntero del ratón" y "puntero del mouse"]

Podemos ver la [aparición brusca de las expresiones](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puntero+del+rat%C3%B3n%2Cpuntero+del+mouse&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpuntero%20del%20rat%C3%B3n%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpuntero%20del%20mouse%3B%2Cc0). Esto no significa que hasta 1993 o hasta 1995 no apareciera ningún libro de informática con las palabras *ratón* o *mouse*, respectivamente: hay que tener en cuenta que hemos disminuido la muestra al buscar la expresión **y** solo estamos considerando los libros que tiene escaneados Google.

También podemos comparar el [uso de una expresión a costa de la otra](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puntero+del+rat%C3%B3n%2F(puntero+del+rat%C3%B3n%2Bpuntero+del+mouse)%2Cpuntero+del+mouse%2F(puntero+del+rat%C3%B3n%2Bpuntero+del+mouse)&year_start=1985&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28puntero%20del%20rat%C3%B3n%20/%20%28puntero%20del%20rat%C3%B3n%20%2B%20puntero%20del%20mouse%29%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28puntero%20del%20mouse%20/%20%28puntero%20del%20rat%C3%B3n%20%2B%20puntero%20del%20mouse%29%29%3B%2Cc0) sumando ambas cifras y calculando la porción de cada una respecto a esa suma. Cuando una sube, la otra baja, claro.

[image: Rivalidad de ambas expresiones]

La gráfica está sin suavizar: así se ven los resultados reales por año. ¿Qué pasó en 2003?. En 2005 se editó el DPD, que incluye la recomendación de usar *ratón*. ¿Hubo algún avance en 2003-2004 al respecto? Sería interesante ver si así fue. Desde aquel año *mouse* fue perdiendo.

Como dije en el comentario de arriba, los escritores y correctores sí consultan estas recomendaciones y suelen estar al tanto de los avances de la RAE (aunque solo sea por aviso de compañeros de profesión). Utilizar una recomendación de la RAE es una forma de acallar la críticas a sus escritos de los partidarios de la opción opuesta, así que eso les proporciona salud mental (aunque ellos utilicen la otra en el habla). Como dije, lo escrito permanece, se lee una y otra vez y va haciendo mella.

Y también está el efecto Mateo que nombré.

Comment: La falta de suavidad también se podría atribuir a la falta de ejemplares. Cuantas más expresiones en que podemos pensar para distinguir este uso de ratón, más suave aparecerá.